# Adding roles to a user (DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to add two buttons to set roles for a user, but I am getting the following error:

```
.../node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
```

I couldn't find any way to overcome this issue from my end.

---

The client has the following flags:

```
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
    ] 
});
```

Comment: After looking into https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#missing-permissions, it seems that my bot's role is lower than some roles. That's why it couldn't add those roles to the user. This issue has been resolved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Discord permissions rather than programming

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but if your bot should have enough permissions and it still doesn't work the problem may be that the role that gives you the permissions is lower in the server role hierarchy than the role you're trying to give.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an intents issue, your bot's user does not have permission to edit that user's roles. Consider checking for permissions before running code.